# Try Catch influencia em performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, exceção

Utilizar `Try...Catch` influencia em performance? em uso de memória?

Teria problema se todas as ações que fizer tiver tratamento de erro?

```
  try
  {
    clienteRepository.Salvar(entity);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    emailService.EnviaErro(e);
  }
```

Comment: @bfavaretto não é duplicata, acho que a edição que você fez ficou mais clara

Comment: Exato Caffé, minha ideia seria na exceção, mandar-me email com o erro que aconteceu, rs

Comment: Uma sugestão: ao desenvolver aplicativos web, preocupe-se com o design do sistema e custo de tráfego de dados, não com micro-otimização-prévia-duvidosa de performance do código.

Comment: Obrigado Caffé, aproveitando sua sugestão, alguma ferramenta para eu analisar o tráfego da aplicação ?

Comment: Agora considerando o código adicionado: não parece uma boa idéia, Rod. Não por questões de performance mas sim por questões de design - este exemplo usa exceções para definir fluxo do aplicativo. Exceções não são pra isso.

Comment: Ao moderadores, a pergunta não está duplicada, na verdade, o que está errado é a pergunta do link citado, e na resposta do link citado acaba por responder minha pergunta, mas a pergunta em si não é duplicada.

Comment: Concordo, Rod: a resposta àquela pergunta responde a sua e as perguntas são diferentes.

Comment: Rod e @Caffé Como a resposta de lá atende, a orientação é fechar como duplicata (mesmo as perguntas não sendo idênticas).

Answer (score -1):

Sim, influencia de forma minima em tempo de execução, a não ser que você faça grandes loops dentro do try, use somente quando necessário e evite usar o Exception, use a exceção de acordo com o tipo de erro que se espera a acontecer, exemplo abrindo um conexao com um bd use SQLException.

E em relação ao desempenho você prefere desempenho ou evitar um crash?